# Upload audio file from document directory to iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I am trying to upload audio file like session1.mp3 from document directory to iCloud using the following code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"session1.mp3"];
NSURL* sourceURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSLog(@"File found!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"File not found!");
}



NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
if (ubiq)
{
    NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURL *destinationURL = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"session1.mp3"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES
                                        itemAtURL:sourceURL
                                   destinationURL:destinationURL
                                            error:&error];

    if(error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while uploading the file: %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"File ulpoaded successfully");
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"No iCloud access");

}
```

The file i am trying to upload exists (the "File found" is printed), but the uploading it to iCloud generates the following error

**Error while uploading the file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x1f03d9f0 {NSURL=file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/20D82CDA-021E-4067-B9AB-C0197A6FA834/dox.app/session1.mp3, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f03d990 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}**

Comment: Your error message does not appear to come from the code that you posted. In your code you're working on a file named `session1.mp3` that's in the documents directory. But your error message complains about a file named `test.png` that's located in the app bundle. Could you resolve this conflict? For one of these files the problem is obvious, but in the other it's difficult to tell.

Comment: I have use this code for upload video file from document directory, and successfully uploaded it but this file become remove from document directory why?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing inherently wrong with your code.

Are you checking the ubiquityIdentityToken anywhere to make sure it is available?

```
[ [ NSFileManager defaultManager ] ubiquityIdentityToken ];
```

Also, in your logging of a successful setUbiquitous, "upload successful" is not exact: the item was simply moved to the ubiquity container, and will be uploaded when the demon feels like it. You can check on the upload status through [NSMetadataQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMetadataQuery_Class/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

You are not supposed to use iCloud to store this media.

Please review the [Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html) given by Apple.

Comment: may i know the reason? is it possible to upload image to icloud

Comment: You may know the reason. Read the human interface guidelines referenced above.

Comment: Those guidelines don't actually say anything like that.

Comment: @TomHarrington They do, actually. Look at "Respect the user’s iCloud space." and "Determine which types of information to store in iCloud."

Comment: I did. Neither one mentions media files.

Comment: "iCloud is a finite resource for which users pay".

Comment: That quote does not mention media files.

Comment: I rest my case. Thanks for following up.

Comment: Even if your answer were accurate, it does not answer the question of why the upload process failed. Even if uploading media or images were forbidden (they're not forbidden) there's no automatic checking of file type. Errors like the one in the question do not result from attempting to upload media files.

Comment: GoodReader recently experienced trouble for uploading files to iCloud. The restriction is simple: Only files created in the app should be uploaded. Apple doesn't enforce it unless your app generates a lot of uploads which violate the guideline, though.